# Cypress How do tick check boxes with no unique selectors

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I am trying to select/tick checkboxes with no obvious selectors but a class name which is shared by all the checkboxes on the page.

Comment: Is the class `ui-lib-general-filter__checkbox` uique ?

Comment: It is not unique, and there are no other selectors I can use to select a checkbox individually. I have included an image above of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Then You can directly use the text to find the locator and click it, something like:

```js
cy.contains('Tool').click()
```

For the search button, you have the aria-label tag, you can use that directly:

```js
cy.get('input[aria-label*="main-search-box"]').type('text')
```

Comment: Thanks Alapan, would the same command work for a clear button which has an X image and a search button with magnifying glass image, both which share the same class selector name with no other selectors. I have added a screen shot above

Comment: `cy.contains` will only search for text content. Add the code for the search bar, I can check then.

Comment: Thank you for the above. But in order to test the search button and text clear button, which both share the same class name, how can you select a unique selector to separate the actions

Answer (score 0):

I believe it goes against cypress' best practices to try and select any element other than using `data-cy="add-unique-id-here"` selector. The docs suggest that using CSS-style selectors is brittle, and may cause tests to fail in the future when you update your code. By using `data-*` selectors, you can gaurantee you're always selecting what you need.

Here's the link for the cypress docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements

[image: Example code from cypress docs]

In your case, adding
`<span class="ui-lib-checkbox__box" data-cy="descriptive-checkbox-name"> <svg>...</svg> </span>` to your html

and `cy.get('[data-cy=descriptive-checkbox-name]')` to your cypress testing file, should do the trick.

Comment: But how can you proceed with the above code when the webpage has a dynamic ID?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean about a "dynamic ID". Are you not running this test locally?

Answer (score 0):

Given the text for the checkboxes are unique, you can use `cy.contains()`

```js
// 'Under 6 min' checkbox
cy.contains('span', 'Under 6 min')

// 'Tool' checkbox
cy.contains('span', 'Tool')
```

As for the search box, it will get a bit trickier. If it is the only search box that is visible on the page you can do the following.

```js
cy.get('input[type=text][placeholder]')
  .filter(':visible')
```